Transaction reading table that may be updated by a different process
We have a cron job that reads a table, and then perform some operations for each row, and then stores the results in a different table.
To put it in an example, let's imagine we have the following tables:
user_orders
|-----|---------|---------------------|----------|
| id. | user_id | order_time          | order_id |
|-----|---------|---------------------|----------|
|  1  |       1 | 2024-10-22 10:10:10 |        1 |
|  2  |       1 | 2024-10-24 10:20:10 |       11 |
|  3  |       2 | 2024-10-23 15:00:00 |        2 |
|  4  |       2 | 2024-10-24 20:10:10 |       22 |
...

orders_report
|-----|------------|---------|----------|--------|--------|-------|
| id  | day        | user_id | order_id | item   | amount | shop  |
|-----|------------|---------|----------|--------|--------|-------|
|  1  | 2024-10-22 |       1 |        1 |  boots |    150 | shopA |
|  2  | 2024-10-23 |       2 |        2 |  shirt |     70 | shopB |
|  3  | 2024-10-23 |       2 |        2 |  pants |     40 | shopB |
|  4  | 2024-10-24 |       1 |       11 |  candy |     2  | shopA |
|  5  | 2024-10-24 |       2 |       22 |  shoes |     60 | shopB |
...     

And there is a cron job that reads the user_orders table, do some processing for each order, and store it in the orders_report table (which contains an unique key based on day,user_id,order_id,item).
That processing works in single transaction:

Remove the entries for the orders_report for that day (if existent) since we are going to calculate them again
Calculate the results to be stored in the orders report using batches (since the table can contain a lot of data, and also the calculation for each order can be memory intensive)
Store the results in the orders_report, also in batches.

The thing is, randomly, we get unique key constraints errors. And I am wondering how the transaction works in PostgreSQL if that table we are processing in batches gets updated by an external connection.
So, imagine that we are processing the table in batches and this would be the normal flow:
Batch number | ids to be processed |
-------------|---------------------|
           0 |                1, 2 |
           1 |                3, 4 |
           2 |                5, 6 |
....

But then, while processing one batch, the table gets updated, will the new batches ignore these new entries? or while doing the limit/offset filtering of the entries can we skip, or process "old" entries?
I hope I explain myself properly.

You are processing  (at least) two tables. So "that table we are processing" is ambiguous. "store it in the orders_report table" could mean INSERT or UPDATE. Show exact commands. It's unclear why you "delete", why "that day", how that correlates to batch sizes, how the example batches correlate to the sample data above, what and to which table(s) concurrent transaction might possibly write, what the actual, literal error message says,  ... Please clarify across the board. And always disclose your version of Postgres.
